# I want to read child keys of root node in real time database using flutter but I get complete data with sub child also

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, flutter-layout

```
void read() {
    DatabaseReference starCountRef =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("/Exam");
    starCountRef.onValue.listen((DatabaseEvent event) {
      final data = event.snapshot.key;
      print(data);
    });
  }
```

here is my real time database structure pic

[image: 1]

Comment: So what are you asking?

Comment: by this code I get whole exam database data while I only want main childs key (i.e spring and fall)

Answer (score 0):

```dart
void exam() async {
    final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
    final snapshot = await ref.child("/Exam").get();
    if (snapshot.exists) {
        print(snapshot.children.length);
        final examvalue = snapshot.children.forEach((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            print(dataSnapshot.key);
        });
    } else {
        print('No data available.');
    }
}
```

Here is the output:
[image: here is the output]